# mysqli_fetch_field doesn't return the first column name

Tags: php

I'm using `mysqli_fetch_field` to auto populate headers names in a `while` loop. I'm getting the headers but it's always missing the first one. I'm using `mysqli_fetch_row` and getting the correct number of columns for the table data.

```
function tableQuery($sql){
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $columns = 0;

    $tableInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($query);
    echo "<center><h1>Results for " . $tableInfo->table . "</h1></center>";

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        while($headers = mysqli_fetch_field($query)) {
            echo "<th>" . $headers->name . "</th>";
            $columns++;
        }
    echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                for ($n = 0; $n <= $columns; $n++) {
                    echo "<td>" . $row[$n] . "</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

If I pass this `$sql = "SELECT id, name, date FROM users"` My output looks like this:

```
name |   date
______________________________
1    |  Michael  |  1/1/2018
______________________________
2    |    Jack   |  2/5/2018
______________________________
3    |    David  |  4/15/2018
```

So it's missing the `id` table header for example.
When I `var_dump($headers->name)` I don't see `id`

Comment: `$tableInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($query);    echo "<center><h1>Results for " . $tableInfo->table . "</h1></center>";` <-- You're fetching the first column name here, which you omitted from your sample output.  Show us that output too?

Comment: @cdhowie, hmmm, you're right, I can see `id` in `$tableInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **@cdhowie**, The problem is I'm fetching the column name in the `$tableInfo` so either remove the table info or do it this way:

```
function tableQuery($sql){
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $columns = 0;
    $headerSet = false;

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        while($headers = mysqli_fetch_field($query)) {
            if(!$headerSet){
                echo "<h1> Results for " . $headers->name . "</h1>";
                headerSet = true;
            }
            echo "<th>" . $headers->name . "</th>";
            $columns++;
        }
    echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                for ($n = 0; $n <= $columns; $n++) {
                    echo "<td>" . $row[$n] . "</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
while($headers = mysqli_fetch_field($query)) {
    echo "<th>" . $headers->name . "</th>";
    $columns++;
}
```

with:

```
do {
    echo "<th>" . $tableInfo->name . "</th>";
    $columns++;
} while($tableInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($query))
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to set the pointer back to 0 (after you have done the query)

mysqli_field_seek($query, 0);

```
...  
mysqli_field_seek($query,0);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    while($headers = mysqli_fetch_field($query)) {
        echo "<th>" . $headers->name . "</th>";
        $columns++;
    }
echo "</tr>";
...
```